# Angular - Make a service call when input has changed onBlur

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to detect if the text of input has changed in onBlur event in Angular.
If yes then perform some action:

Conditions to process on the blur:

- It should only capture/process only if the text input has changed.
- If input hasn't changed then it shouldn't be processed.

Here is the stackblitz link for the version of code which has blur event established. But it logs in console even if input isn't changed:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-blur-8er79o?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do:

1. When the element is focused, save the current value
2. When the element loses focus, compare the current value to the saved
   value
3. Do the processing if the value has changed

```
<input (focus)="saveValue()" (blur)="processChange()" [(ngModel)]="someValue" ... />
```

```
someValue = "nice";
prevValue = this.someValue;

saveValue() {
  this.prevValue = this.someValue;
}

processChange() {
  if (this.someValue !== this.prevValue) {
    console.log("The value has changed!!!");
    // Do some additional processing...
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-blur-d62gjd) for a demo.

---

If you don't want to change the component code, save the value in an attribute of the element:

```
<input #txt type="text" name="field" 
  (focus)="txt.setAttribute('data-value', someValue)" 
  (blur)="txt.getAttribute('data-value') !== someValue ? processChange() : ''" 
  [(ngModel)]="someValue" />
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-blur-mm96nf) for a demo.

Comment: thanks for solution. I was trying to find out a solutions without using an extra variable. Any clue on that?

Comment: I added an alternative solution.

Comment: You can create an single object with 2 properties prevValue and curValue and store the data. Using this an extra variable can be removed.

Comment: the second solution is pretty neato